# Regex to replace multiple occurence of @ except first

Tags: c#, regex

I have an email "xyz@gmail@.com", which contains two @ characters. What I want is to keep the first @ character and remove all the remaining 2 characters (even if there are more than two @ characters in email).

What I had tried to do is:

```
Regex.Replace("xyz@gmail@.com", @"^([^,]*@[^,]*)@(.*)$", "")
```

but it is returning empty string. I am not sure how to replace the 2nd character, even I am not sure if I have correctly chosen the regex pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!^[^@]*)@", "");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5B%5E%40%5D*%29%40&i=santychavez2004%40gmail%40.com&r=). Details:

- `(?<!^[^@]*)` - a negative lookbehind that makes sure there is no `@` before the current location up to the string start
- `@` - a `@` in other contexts.

In case you do not really have to use a regex,

```
var result = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("@")+1) + text.Substring(text.IndexOf("@")+1).Replace("@", "");
```

should also work. See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/W2eS2B).

Answer (score 0):

Regex will only match one occurrence, you can do this without regex though:

```
var parts = text.Split("@");
var result = parts[0] + "@" + string.Join("", parts.Skip(1));
```